# FTP file acces problem

Tags: nautilus, ftp

I have a problem with removing files from the FTP server. I have access to the server. The output of rm and ls listed below

```
$ touch file.txt
touch: setting times of 'file.txt': Operation not supported
$ ls -la
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 adrian adrian 0 Jun 21  2020 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 adrian adrian 0 Jun 21  2020 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 adrian adrian 0 Jun 21  2020 file.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 adrian adrian 0 Jun 21  2020 wowo
-rwxrwxrwx 1 adrian adrian 0 Jun 21  2020 wowo.txt
$ sudo rm -f file.txt
rm: cannot remove 'file.txt': Permission denied
```

Is it a server configuration problem or I didn't connect properly.
It is connected through nautilus with anonymous access.

Comment: After some more research:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141142/why-cant-anonymous-users-delete-files-via-ftp
Missing one option in vsftpd.conf

Comment: Would you write an answer here, even by just copying that answer from UnixSE.